# Can we find the individual scores of 4 players given the total of player 1 & 2, player 2 & 3, player 3 & 4, and player 4 & 1? (Linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a problem from a past course I took.

[image: Linear Algebra Question]

I concluded (for part b)  ), by using elementary row operations, that
(where a,b, c, and d are assumed to be known)

$$\left[
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{matrix}
  \left|
    \,
    \begin{matrix}
      a-b+c  \\
      b-c  \\
      c  \\
      d-a+b-c  \\
    \end{matrix}
  \right.
\right]$$

starting from the matrix

$$\left[
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{matrix}
  \left|
    \,
    \begin{matrix}
      a  \\
      b  \\
      c  \\
      d  \\
    \end{matrix}
  \right.
\right]$$

Since $x_{4}$ is a parameter, there is no way to determine the individual scores of each of the players because of $x_{4}$. Is this correct? Could someone please verify because I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "I concluded that [matrix]." I do not understand how to interpret this matrix as the second half of your sentence.

Comment: You can see it straight away: If you add $(1\&2)+(3\&4)-(2\&3)=(1\&4)$ so the equations are not independent.

Comment: I've edited the post for clarification, please let me know if further clarification is needed

Comment: All you need is one single example of two different quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ giving the same values of $a+b,b+c,c+d,a+d$.

Comment: Do you understand what we're saying in these comments, Curious? Do they answer your question?